# Conditionnel passé: reproche, information non confirmée par le dialogue

Tags: grammaire

Mère: Mon vase est cassé. Pourquoi tu aurais cassé mon vase ?
Fille: C’était pas moi, c’était ma sœur...
Mère: mais pourquoi elle aurait cassé mon vase ?
Fille: c’était pas fait exprès.

Est-ce qu’on peut utiliser le conditionnel passé dans un reproche direct ou est-ce qu’il faut une phrase indirecte ? *Elle m’a dit que tu aurais cassé mon vase ?*

Answer (score 1):

Le conditionnel passé va bien et insiste justement sur le fait que l'information n'est pas retenue comme exprimant un état de fait à l'instant de la question. On peut aussi utiliser le passé composé, mais la notion de doute qui est communiquée par le conditionnel n'est presque plus ressentie.

- Pourquoi as-tu cassé mon vase ?
- Pourquoi tu as cassé mon vase ?
- Pourquoi t'as cassé mon vase ?

Une tournure indirecte ne convient pas parce qu'elle est propre à la narration ; de plus « pourquoi » ne pourrait porter que sur « dire » pas sur « casser »;

- Pourquoi m'a-t-elle dit « Elle a cassé ton vase » ?

Si elle était utilisée, le locuteur raconterait tout simplement ce qui lui a été dit et le souci même de savoir si le vase a été cassé et/ou qui a commis cette action ne serait plus nécessairement perçu comme l'idée première du propos.

Answer (score 1):

Ce dialogue ne sonne pas juste.

En supposant que tu l'as écrit toi-même, le mieux serait que tu expliques ce que tu souhaites exprimer.

La première réplique est contradictoire :
*Pourquoi tu aurais cassé mon vase* implique que la fille a avoué qu'elle avait l'intention de casser le vase mais qu'elle ne l'a pas fait, or on vient de dire que le vase est cassé.

La deuxième réplique utilise l'imparfait. On préfère généralement le présent (*c'est pas moi, c'est ma sœur*) sauf si la situation a changé ( ex.: *c'était pas moi ce jour là*).

La dernière réplique n'est pas tout à fait ce à quoi on s'attend : *C’était pas fait exprès* signifie quelque chose comme *Ça n'avait pas d'objectif particulier*.
J'aurais plutôt écrit *Elle (l')a pas fait exprès*, c'est à dire, elle n'avait pas l'intention de le faire, c'est un accident.

---

These sentences do not sound right.

Assuming you wrote them yourself, better for you to explain what you intend to express.

The first line has two contradictory statements:

> ***Mon vase est cassé**.* My vase is broken.

> ***Pourquoi tu aurais cassé mon vase ?*** Why would you have broken my vase ?

This implies that the vase is not broken and the daughter told she intended to broke the vase but didn't do it.

> ***C'était pas moi, c'était ma sœur***

That looks like the expected meaning is "That wasn't me but my sister" but in French, we prefer the present here *C'est pas moi, c'est ma sœur*.

The third line is fine:

> ***Mais pourquoi elle aurait cassé mon vase ?*** "But why would she have broken my vase?"

The fourth is slightly off:

> ***C’était pas fait exprès***.

That means "It wasn't made on purpose". I would rather have written *Elle (l')a pas fait exprès* (She didn't intend to do it.)